# Angular custom validation: ensure form control is invalid when the form group has validation errors

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I am working on reactive forms in angular. I have  set up fields for `Password` and `Confirm password` as shown below. I am using custom validation to make sure that the `Password` field matches the `Confirm password` field. The problem is, although, on console logging, i can see that the forms `error` property has `mismatch` set to `true`, the `confirm password` field is still valid and  thus,the form is still valid.

1. How can I ensure that the `Confirm Password` field is also invalid when the form has `mismatch` property set in `errors` property?
2. If I attach `passwordMatchValidator` to `confirmPassword`(in formcontrol definition) instead of setting up in `formGroup` level , then how do i set up my validation?

My component template

```
    <form [formGroup]="registerForm" (ngSubmit)="onRegister()">
        <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password"
        class="form-control" placeholder="Password" formControlName="password">
        <div class="invalid-feedback"  *ngIf="registerForm.get('password').hasError('required')">Password is required</div>
        <div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="registerForm.get('password').hasError('minlength')">Password must be at least 5 characters</div>
        <div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="registerForm.get('password').hasError('maxlength')">Password cannot exceed 8 characters</div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password"
        class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password" formControlName="confirmPassword">
        <div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="registerForm.get('confirmPassword').hasError('required')">Password is required</div>
        <div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="registerForm.hasError('mismatch')">Password must match</div>
      </div>
     </form>
```

Css to show/hide error feedback

```
.ng-valid{
    border: 1px solid green;
}
.ng-invalid.ng-touched + .invalid-feedback{
    display: block;
}
```

And my component looks like following:

```
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {

 registerForm: FormGroup

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.registerForm = this.fb.group({
      "password": [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5), Validators.maxLength(8)]],
      "confirmPassword": [null, [Validators.required]]
    },{
      validators:this.passwordMatchValidator
    });
  }
  passwordMatchValidator(f:FormGroup):{[s:string]:boolean} {
    return f.controls['password'].value === f.controls['confirmPassword'].value ? null : { 'mismatch': true }
  }

  onRegister() {
    console.log(this.registerForm)
  }
}
```

I have setup a debugger inside passwordMatchValidator and tried console logging as shown below
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have used below code for password validation.

```js
//In init method
this.signUpForm = this._fb.group({
     
      password: ['',
        [Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(8),
        Validators.pattern(this._config.PASSWORD_REGEX)
        ]
      ],
      confirmPassword: ['',
        Validators.required
      ]
    });
this.signUpForm.get('password').valueChanges
      .subscribe(value => this.validatePassword(value));
    
//method
validatePassword(value: any): void {
    let ctrl = this.signUpForm.get('password');
    this.numberError = true;
    this.letterError = true;
    this.lengthError = true;

    if (/[a-z]/.test(value) && /[A-Z]/.test(value)) {
      this.letterError = false;
    }

    if (/[0-9]/.test(value)) {
      this.numberError = false;
    }

    if (value.length >= 8) {
      this.lengthError = false;
    }
  }
//Method match text
matchText(controlType: string): void {
    let control1 = null, control2 = null;

  if (controlType == 'password') {
      control1 = this.signUpForm.get('password');
      control2 = this.signUpForm.get('confirmPassword');
    }


    if (control1.value && control2.value) {
      if (control1.value != control2.value) {
        control2.setValidators(this.matchValidator());
      } else {
        control2.setValidators([Validators.required]);
      }

      control2.updateValueAndValidity();
    }
  }
//match validator method
  matchValidator(): ValidatorFn {
    return (c: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null => {
      return { 'match': false };
    };
  }
```

```html
<mat-form-field>
          <input autocomplete="nope" formControlName="password" matInput placeholder="PASSWORD" [type]="hidePassword ? 'password' : 'text'"
            (change)="matchText('password')" maxlength="30">
          <mat-icon matSuffix (click)="hidePassword = !hidePassword">{{hidePassword ? 'visibility' : 'visibility_off'}}</mat-icon>
          <mat-hint align="start" class="signup_hint">
            <span>PASSWORD_MUST_HAVE...</span>
            <br>
            <span [ngClass]="{'hint-error': (((signUpForm.get('password').dirty ||
            signUpForm.get('password').touched) && signUpForm.get('password').invalid) &&
            signUpForm.get('password')?.errors?.required) || signUpForm.get('password')?.errors?.minlength || lengthError, '': !(((signUpForm.get('password').dirty ||
            signUpForm.get('password').touched) && signUpForm.get('password').invalid) &&
            signUpForm.get('password')?.errors?.required) && !signUpForm.get('password')?.errors?.minlength && !lengthError }">&nbsp; &nbsp;HINT_8_CHARACTERS</span>
            <br>


            <span [ngClass]="{'hint-error': signUpForm.get('password')?.errors?.pattern && letterError, '': !signUpForm.get('password')?.errors?.pattern && !letterError }">&nbsp; &nbsp; HINT_UPPER_AND_LOWER</span>
            <br>
            <span [ngClass]="{'hint-error': signUpForm.get('password')?.errors?.pattern && numberError, '': !signUpForm.get('password')?.errors?.pattern && !numberError }">&nbsp; &nbsp; HINT_AT_LEAST_ONE</span>

            <br/>
             </mat-hint>
        </mat-form-field>

     

        <mat-form-field>
          <input autocomplete="nope" formControlName="confirmPassword" matInput placeholder="CONFIRM_PASSWORD" [type]="hidePassword ? 'password' : 'text'"
            (change)="matchText('password')" (paste)="$event.preventDefault()">
          <mat-icon matSuffix (click)="hidePassword = !hidePassword">{{hidePassword ? 'visibility' : 'visibility_off'}}</mat-icon>
          <mat-error *ngIf="(signUpForm.get('confirmPassword').dirty || signUpForm.get('confirmPassword').touched) &&
          signUpForm.get('confirmPassword').invalid">(signUpForm.get('confirmPassword')?.errors?.required ? 'ERR_REQUIRED_FIELD' : 'ERR_PASSWORD_MISMATCH')</mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Serendra, you has not a "custom validator", you only check in onChange if the passwords match, so you loose the potential of validators :(

Answer (score 0):

you can use a css like:

```
/*Only border green/red the "form controls" nor the div*/

.form-control.ng-valid{
    border: 1px solid green;
}
.form-control.ng-invalid.ng-touched{
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.ng-invalid.ng-touched + .invalid-feedback{
    display: block;
}
/*Is invalid? the formControls valid and touched inside border red*/
.ng-invalid .form-control.ng-valid.ng-touched 
{
    border: 1px solid red!important;

}
```

See that the ng-invalid is the formgroup itself (use Navigators tools F12 to see where the class is applied)